# How to properly manage the services and interfaces for the same model with Sequelize when I sometimes want to fetch associations and sometimes not?

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, rest, sequelize.js

I'm developing REST APIs with Node.js + TypeScript + Sequelize, and I have a little library system whose sequelize model definitions are like below:

```js
export interface Book {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  authorId: number;
  borrowerId: number;
}

export const BookModel = sequelize.define<Model<Book, Book>>('book', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  authorId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'author',
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
  borrowerId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'borrower',
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
});

BookModel.belongsTo(AuthorModel);
AuthorModel.hasMany(BookModel);

BookModel.belongsTo(BorrowerModel);
BorrowerModel.hasMany(BookModel);
```

```js
export interface Author {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export const AuthorModel = sequelize.define<Model<Author, Author>>('author', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

```js
export interface Borrower {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  countryId: number;
}

export const BorrowerModel = sequelize.define<Model<Borrower, Borrower>>('borrower', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  countryId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'country',
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
});

BorrowerModel.belongsTo(CountryModel);
CountryModel.hasMany(BorrowerModel);
```

```js
export interface Country {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export const CountryModel = sequelize.define<Model<Country, Country>>('country', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

In order to make the API calls simple and efficient, I want to fetch all associations for a resource (ex. Book) when there comes a HTTP request from the front-end, so I queried resources with Sequelize and provided the `include` option to fetch all associations and it worked perfectly.

But later I found it hard to manage interfaces and services for the same model in different situations. For example, sometimes I want to fetch all associations for the view models rendered in the front-end, but sometimes I might just want to query a resource with zero or one association in the middle of other services.

I'm wondering what the best practice is when you develop services for the same model in different situations, and here are my questions:

1. Should I wrap all data access operations into functions?

```js
// Is it always better to access data through a wrapper function (ex. getBook()) than calling BookModel directly?
async function getBook(id: number): Promise<Book | undefined> {
  const book = (await BookModel.findByPk(id))?.toJSON();
  return book;
}
```

2. How do you manage the interfaces and services for a model whose query result could be with or without associations?

```js
//I have a service which queries without any associations.
//But what if I need and only need the association of Author next time?
//Should I need to create services for "every combination" of associations?
async function getBook(id: number): Promise<Book | undefined> {
  const book = (await BookModel.findByPk(id))?.toJSON();
  return book;
}
```

```js
interface BookWithAssociations extends Book {
  author: Author;
  borrower: BorrowerWithAssociations;
}

interface BorrowerWithAssociations extends Borrower {
  country: Country;
}

async function getBookWithAllAssociations(id: number): Promise<BookWithAssociations | undefined> {
  //I created extra interfaces for the situation of querying all associations.
  //But what if I don't need the author's detail next time?
  const book: BookWithAssociations | undefined = (
    await BookModel.findByPk(id, {
      include: [AuthorModel, { model: BorrowerModel, include: [CountryModel] }],
    })
  )?.toJSON<BookWithAssociations>();

  return book;
}
```

3. If the answer to the previous question is creating more interfaces and services, as the number of interfaces and services for the same model increases, will it be hard to manage them when I change or add a column in a table? For example, I need to modify ALL interfaces and services once a column is added.

Comment: Did you try to define all associations like it presented in the official documentation here: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript ?